# White label page error using Netflix Zuul

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-zuul

I am practicing to use Load Balancing using Netflix Zuul and Eureka Server on Spring Boot. And I've encountered a problem.
So I've created 2 Spring Boot project. One project for creating Eureka Server and one for creating Eureka Client. Here is the code of both project.

Eureka Server project

```java
package com.example.eureka;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.server.EnableEurekaServer;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaServer
public class EurekaServerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(EurekaServerApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

and `application.yaml`

```
# This default profile is used when running a single instance completely standalone:
spring:
  profiles: default
server:
  port: 9000  
eureka:
  instance:
    hostname: my-eureka-server.com
  client:
    registerWithEureka: false
    fetchRegistry: false
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://${eureka.instance.hostname}:${server.port}/eureka/    

---
spring:
  profiles: united-states
  application:
    name: eureka-server-clustered   # ==> This is Service-Id
server:
  port: 9001  
eureka:
  instance:
    hostname: my-eureka-server-us.com    
  client:
    registerWithEureka: false
    fetchRegistry: false       
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://my-eureka-server-fr.com:9002/eureka/,http://my-eureka-server-vn.com:9003/eureka/

---
spring:
  profiles: france
  application:
    name: eureka-server-clustered   # ==> This is Service-Id   
server:
  port: 9002
eureka:
  instance:
    hostname: my-eureka-server-fr.com      
  client:
    registerWithEureka: false
    fetchRegistry: false  
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://my-eureka-server-us.com:9001/eureka/,http://my-eureka-server-vn.com:9003/eureka/

---
spring:
  profiles: vietnam
  application:
    name: eureka-server-clustered    # ==> This is Service-Id  
server:
  port: 9003
eureka:
  instance:
    hostname: my-eureka-server-vn.com    
  client:
    registerWithEureka: false
    fetchRegistry: false  
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://my-eureka-server-us.com:9001/eureka/,http://my-eureka-server-fr.com:9002/eureka/
```

I already added new domain name into `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\host` 
And the Eureka_Client project

```
package com.example.config;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.client.discovery.DiscoveryClient;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Lazy;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

import com.netflix.discovery.EurekaClient;

@SpringBootApplication
@Controller
public class EurekaClientApplication {
    @Autowired
    private DiscoveryClient discoveryClient;

    @Autowired
    @Lazy
    private EurekaClient eurekaClient;

    @Value("${eureka.instance.appname}")
    private String appName;

    @Value("${server.port}")
    private String port;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(EurekaClientApplication.class, args);
    }
    @RequestMapping("/client")
    public String getService(Model m) {
        List<String> listService = discoveryClient.getServices();
        String name = eurekaClient.getApplication(appName).getName();
        String info = "Name app: " + name + " Port: " + port;
        m.addAttribute("info",info);
        m.addAttribute("listService",listService);
        return "service";
    }
    @RequestMapping("/home")
    public String goHome() {
        return "home";
    }

}
```

and `application.yaml`

```
spring:
  application:
    name: ABC-SERVICE # ==> This is Service-Id


---
# Items that apply to ALL profiles:   
eureka:
  instance:
    appname: ABC-SERVICE  # ==> This is a instance of ABC-SERVICE
  client:   
    fetchRegistry: true
    serviceUrl:   
      defaultZone: http://my-eureka-server-us.com:9001/eureka

server:
  port: 8000  

---
spring:
  profiles: firstService
eureka:
  instance:
    appname: ABC-SERVICE  # ==> This is a instance of ABC-SERVICE
    preferIpAddress: true
  client:   
    fetchRegistry: true
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://my-eureka-server-us.com:9001/eureka  

server:
  port: 8001   

---
spring:
  profiles: secondService
eureka:
  instance:
    appname: ABC-SERVICE  # ==> This is a instance of ABC-SERVICE
    preferIpAddress: true
  client:   
    fetchRegistry: true
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://my-eureka-server-us.com:9001/eureka   

server:
  port: 8002

---
spring:
  profiles: thirdService
eureka:
  instance:
    appname: ABC-SERVICE  # ==> This is a instance of ABC-SERVICE
    preferIpAddress: true  
  client:   
    fetchRegistry: true
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://my-eureka-server-us.com:9001/eureka  

server:
  port: 8003
```

I runned both two project with different spring profile in the same time and it works very well. When I hit this URL `http://localhost:8001/home` or `http://localhost:8001/service` it returns exactly what I want.
And then I created a project for Netflix Zuul and here is its `application.yaml` file

```
eureka:
  client:
    fetchRegistry: true
    registerWithEureka: true
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://my-eureka-server-us.com:9001/eureka
  instance:
    preferIpAddress: true
server:
  port: 8762
spring:
  application:
    name: zuul-server
```

And when I hit this url `localhost:8762/ABC-SERVICE/home`or `localhost:8762/ABC-SERVICE/client` the browser return white label page error.
I know there is something wrong with the configuration of Netflix Zuul in my project. Can you guy help me to figure it out?

Comment: What do you see in the logs of your apps?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you didn't configure your routes.
Here's some information on how to configure this: https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-netflix/2.1.2.RELEASE/single/spring-cloud-netflix.html#netflix-zuul-reverse-proxy

EDIT: If you forgot the `@EnableZuulProxy` annotation, that will most likely be the cause.